# mhddfs Gives Permission denied Error When Writing File to It's Mounted Volume

Tags: ubuntu, fuse

Running mhddfs 0.1.38 on Ubuntu-12.04 and have two NFS volumes exported from two different servers and mounted to this box.  I can successfully create the mhddfs volume, I can read and list from it, but can not create or edit any files on it.  If I try to edit a file via it's NFS mountpoint, there is no problems; only via the mhddfs mount.

```
user1@mhddfs-1:~$ ls -l /mnt/virtual/
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 1511 May  7 17:50 testfile.txt
user1@mhddfs-1:~$ echo "hello" >> /mnt/virtual/testfile.txt
-bash: /mnt/virtual/testfile.txt: Permission denied
user1@mhddfs-1:~$ echo "hello" >> /mnt/nfs1/testfile.txt
user1@mhddfs-1:~$ ls -l /mnt/virtual/
total 4
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user1 user1 1517 May  7 18:19 testfile.txt
user1@mhddfs-1:~$ mhddfs --version
mhddfs version: 0.1.38
user1@mhddfs-1:~$ tail -1 /etc/fstab
mhddfs#/mnt/nfs1,/mnt/nfs2  /mnt/virtual fuse defaults,allow_other,logfile=/var/log/mhddfs.log,loglevel=0 0 0
user1@mhddfs-1:~$ mount | grep mhddfs
/mnt/nfs1;/mnt/nfs2 on /mnt/virtual type fuse.mhddfs (rw,allow_other)
user1@mhddfs-1:~$
```

I have debugging turned on for logging and the only relevant entries are:

```
mhddfs [2015-05-07 17:50:43]: [140344990897920] mhdd_stat: /testfile.txt
mhddfs [2015-05-07 17:50:43]: [140344999290624] mhdd_fileopen: /testfile.txt, flags = 8401
mhddfs [2015-05-07 17:50:43] (info): [140344999290624] mhdd_internal_open: /testfile.txt, flags = 0x8401
mhddfs [2015-05-07 17:50:43] (info): [140344999290624] mhdd_fileopen: error: Permission denied
```

I saw a previous answer where this was fixed with an entry in /etc/fuse.conf, but that did not work for me:

```
user1@mhddfs-1:~$ cat /etc/fuse.conf
# Set the maximum number of FUSE mounts allowed to non-root users.
# The default is 1000.
#
#mount_max = 1000

# Allow non-root users to specify the 'allow_other' or 'allow_root'
# mount options.
#
user_allow_other
user1@mhddfs-1:~$
```

I can write to the NFS mount, so that piece is good, I just can't write to the mhddfs mount.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is an issue with nfs-kernel-server and how it works with fuse.  Something with how it presents it's exported volume to the client and that that doesn't play well with fuse.  It was suggested to try a user-mode NFS server like Ganesha but even Ganesha had this same issue.